# Context bound for varargs

Tags: scala, variadic-functions, implicit, scala-cats, context-bound

Few days ago I started to learn [Cats](https://typelevel.org/cats) and I want to implement method `appendOptional` for `Map[String, _: Show]`.

I started with the following idea:

```
def appendOptional[T: Show](to: Map[String, String], values: (String, Option[T])*): Map[String, String] = 
    values.foldLeft(values) {
        case (collector, (key, Some(value))) => 
            collector + (key -> implicitly[Show[T]].show(value)) 
        case (collector, _) => collector
    }
```

And to use it like:

```
def createProps(initial: Map[String, String], name: Option[String], age: Option[Int])

val initial = Map("one" -> "one", "two" -> "two")
val props = appendOptional(initial, "name" -> name, "age" -> age)
```

I understand that this approach is quite naive and straightforward because `implicitly[Show[T]].show(value)` will actually lookup for `Show[Any]`.

Also, I had an idea to accept `HList` with context bound, but I have not found any example of that.

One more variant is to create a lot of overloaded methods (as it is done in a lot of libraris):

```
def appendOptional[T1: Show, T2: Show](to: Map[String, String], v1: (String, Option[T1], v2: (String, Option[T2])))
```

**Question**: Is there a way to define context bound for varargs functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the first *is* the correct way to define the bound; varargs don't mean the type of arguments varies, only their number.

The way to achieve what you want with varying types is more involved and requires packing `Show` instances together with values. E.g.

```
case class HasShow[A](x: A)(implicit val ev: Show[A])

def appendOptional(to: Map[String, String], values: (String, Option[HasShow[_]])*): Map[String, String] =     
    values.foldLeft(values) {
        // value.ev.show(value.x)) can be extracted into a method on HasShow as well
        case (collector, (key, Some(value: HasShow[a]))) => 
            collector + (key -> value.ev.show(value.x)) 
        case (collector, _) => collector
    }

val props = appendOptional(initial, "name" -> name.map(HasShow(_)), "age" -> age.map(HasShow(_)))
```

You can sprinkle some more implicit conversions for `HasShow` to simplify the call-site, but this way you can see what's going on better.

For this specific case I think a better and simpler solution would be

```
implicit class MapOp(self: Map[String, String]) extends AnyVal {
    def appendOptional[A: Show](key: String, value: Option[A]) =  
        value.fold(self)(x => self + (key -> Show.show(x)))
}

val props = initial.appendOptional("name", name).appendOptional("age", age)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, you are right, I have already implemented the seconds variant. Although method chaining is simple to implement, the would be a bit of boilerplate code which could be avoided with generic method. Nevertheless, I agree that second approach is simpler and much more maintainable and explicit.

Comment: The problem is that the first way has, if anything, more boilerplate code. It is still useful in many situations.